# Adding a value to an integer stored as a byte array

Tags: arrays, byte, rust

What would be the best way to *add* (not *append*) a value to an array of bytes where the array is treated as a single integer?

For example:

```
let arr = [0xFF, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x43];
```

Assume `arr` may be of any length. If I add 350 to this, for example, the new array should be: `[0xFF, 0x01, 0xC4, 0xA1]`. The solution I've come up with only works if we're incrementing by 1, therefore I'd need to call the method in a loop `amount` times, which can be inefficient with large `amount`'s (this example uses `Vec`'s instead of an array):

```
fn increment_byte_vec(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut done = false;

    vec.iter().rev().map(|&v| {
        if done {
            v
        } else if v == 0xFF {
            0
        } else {
            done = true;
            v + 1
        }
    }).rev().collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

How would I adapt the above so that the function can take an `amount` parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much to say here; just add and carry along the vector, back to front.

It's possible for the number to overflow. I chose to return the carry; you might prefer to extend the vector. My solution uses mutation, since it's much more efficient than allocating a new vector, and since I wasn't changing the length I thought it was nicer to go generic over a mutable slice.

```
/// Increments the bytes, assuming the most significant
/// bit is first, and returns the carry.
fn increment_bytes(b256: &mut [u8], mut amount: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut i = b256.len() - 1;

    while amount > 0 {
        amount += b256[i] as u64;
        b256[i] = amount as u8;
        amount /= 256;

        if i == 0 { break; }
        i -= 1;
    }

    amount
}

fn main() {
    let mut input = vec![0xFF, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x43];
    println!("{}", increment_bytes(&mut input, 350));
    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I am surprised that `amount as u8` is not considered an overflow; I would have expected Rust to require the modulo to be explicit before casting. Do you know if this is here to stay, or should be wary of an overflow check being added in the future?

Comment: @MatthieuM. ["Casting from a larger integer to a smaller integer (e.g. u32 -> u8) will truncate"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/casting-between-types.html#numeric-casts)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically implementing sum in base 256. One way of tackling this is to convert to decimal, add 350 and reconvert the result to base 256.

I.e. `[0xFF, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x43]` is:

```
255 (FF) * 256^3 +
1        * 256^2 +
195 (C3) * 256^1 +
67  (43) * 256^0 = 4,278,305,603 (base10)

4,278,305,603 + 350 = 4_278_305_953
```

Now you need to reconvert this to base 256. This last bit might look like this in Rust:

```
// warning, does not handle overflows
fn base10_to_256(n: u64) -> [u8; 4] {
    let mut converted_number = [0u8; 4];
    let mut number_to_convert = n;
    let base = 256u64;

    for index in 0.. {
         converted_number[3-index] = (number_to_convert % base) as u8;
         number_to_convert = number_to_convert / base;
         if number_to_convert == 0 { break; }
    }

    converted_number
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/544Rpr)

Comment: Note the "Assume `arr` may be of any length." part of the question.